# Enviar json atraves de ajax a sockect.io

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, nodejs

he intentado enviar un array atraves de ajax a un servidor el cual lo emitira a todos los usuarios conectados pero lo envia vacio , si lo envio normal osea solo la data si lo enviar pero en modo json y no quiero que envie el array entero tal caul aqui les dejo mi codigo para que me entiendan mejor ojala y me puedan ayudar

**este es el callback que envio a ajax desde insertar_mensajes.php**

```
$data[]=array('number_m' => $count_msg2 ,'my_session_id' => $yo , 'foto' => $picture,'mensajito' => $textoChat ,'userid' => $dato);

 echo json_encode($data);
```

**luego desde ajax lo siguiente**

```
 $.ajax({

        url:"insertar_mensajes.php",
        type:"GET",
        data:$(".formi").serialize(),
        datatype:"json", 

        success: function(data){
       //si mando solo el data si funciona y manda el json tal cual
      /*pero yo necesito desglosar ese json para mostrarlo en sus etiquetas 
       correspondientes*/
        socket.emit('notification',{

         mypic:      data[0].foto, 
         msgNotify:  data[0].number_m,
         mySession:  data[0].my_session_id,
         comentario: data[0].mensajito,
         myfriend:   data[0].userid });    


         }

      });
```

lo envia vacio al servidor nodejs pero si solo mando data si lo envia **ejemplo**

```
$.ajax({

        url:"insertar_mensajes.php",
        type:"GET",
        data:$(".formi").serialize(),
        datatype:"json", 

        success: function(data){

        socket.emit('notification',data);



         }

      });
```

desde el servidor nodejs lo envio como se debe pero nada siempre me dice undefined en la etiqueta que lo quiero mostrar por no manda el json ,ejemplo del emit desde el servidor **nodejs**

```
socket.on('notification', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        io.sockets.emit('notification',{

            mypic: data.mypic, 
            msgNotify: data.msgNotify,
            mySession: data.my_session_id,
            comentario: data.mensajito,
            myfriend:   data.userid });

    });
```

cualquier ayuda o tips es agradecido gracias!

Comment: jsonifica el subset del array, sino estarías enviando un objeto

Comment: como lo jsonificarias perdon esque no soy muy bueno con eso de json :(

Comment: Ya probaste a encerrar entre comillas los índices mypic, msgNotify, etc.?

Comment: sip y nada @Triby